# print <<< HTML in php?

Tags: php

I am not an expert on PHP.  I have been given a task of adding a small amount of PHP code onto a page of an existing project.  Through out the project, I am seeing code like

```
print <<< HTML
<h1>blah blah blah</h1>
HTML;
```

I have looked into the print method, and have not found discussion about the <<< HTML portion.

Does anyone know why this is how it is?

Thanks

Comment: It's called [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called a [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), which is just a way of defining a multiline string.

Answer (score 1):

It's heredoc syntax.  It essentially means print everything starting on the next line until you reach a line that consists solely of "HTML".

if you wanted to save that text to a variable, it would look like:

```
$text <<< HTML
<h1>blah blah blah</h1>
HTML;
```

Which is functionally equivalent to:

```
$text = "<h1>blah blah blah</h1>";
```

Not really useful with a single line like your example, but with larger blocks of text it's a bit easier to read and edit multi-line blocks without having to deal with concatenating a bunch of quoted lines with line breaks.